# Project Euler #3 - Finding Prime Factors

Tags: php, math

**SPOILER**

This is about question 3 on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) if you want to try it do not read ahead as it contains the answer!

---

So the objective is to find the largest prime factor for a number the code I have written does this but fails when the number gets to big and I can't work out why, I was wondering if someone could take a look for me. The only thing I can think of is that the number is too large for some of PHP's data types?

I will paste my code, if you don't have a local test environment you can paste the code onto here, http://writecodeonline.com/php/

The theory (I'm sure there are much more efficient ways to solve this but I'm neither a mathematician nor a fluent coder), is that it will start at a number which has to be higher than all of the prime factors, it then sequentially tried to divide the starting number by another number, if the result is an integer it runs the process again and again until it no longer gives an integer (must be a prime factor). It then divides the starting number by this prime factor to get a new number which it then plugs back into the first function to get a new prime number and another number, it keeps doing this until all numbers are prime. Then there is a simple check for the largest prime.

It works up until a very large number, i.e if you test with `13195` you get `29` as the largest prime but if you test with `600851475143` (The question) it gives that as the largest prime which isn't right. I know that the answer is `6857` so I make sure that my starting counter is larger than it but it still fails - I can't work out why.

Thanks for your time, here is the code (again I know there will be more efficient methods, I would like to know why mine doesn't work).

Here's the code:

```
$startVal = 13195;
echo "<b>Starting Value</b> = $startVal<br /><br />";

$scriptTime = -microtime(true);

$testVar = 10000;
$primeArray = array();
$processArray = "";

function findPrimes($startStart,$startTest, array & $primeArray, $processArray) {
    $test = $startTest;
    $start = $startStart;
    $holdVal = NULL;
    for ($i=$test; $i > 1 ; $i--) { 
        if(is_int($start/$i) && $start != $i) {
            $processArray .= "$start is divisible by $i<br />";
            $start = $i;
            $i = $test +1;
        }
    }
    $processArray .= "Can't Divide Further<br /><b>Found a Prime : <font     color='red'>$start</font></b><br />";
    $primeArray[] = $start;
    if($start != $startStart) {
        $holdVal = $startStart/$start;
    }
    if(isset($holdVal)) {
        findPrimes($holdVal,$startTest,$primeArray,$processArray);
    }
    return array($primeArray,$processArray);
}

echo "Finding Primes...<br />";

$returnArray = findPrimes($startVal,$testVar,$primeArray,$processArray);
$primeArray = $returnArray[0];
$processArray = $returnArray[1];

echo "Script Found <b>".count($primeArray)."</b> Prime Numbers (";
for ($i=count($primeArray)-1; $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
    if(!$i == 0)
        echo $primeArray[$i].", ";
    else
        echo $primeArray[$i].")";
}
echo "<br />The largest Prime Factor of $startVal is <b><font     color='red'>".max($primeArray)."</font></b><br />";
$scriptTime = round(($scriptTime += microtime(true))* 1000, 3);
echo "<i>Script took $scriptTime milliseconds<br />";
echo "<br /><br /><b>Process</b><br />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($processArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Also ignore the process text bit, I can't get that to work

Comment: Is your processor or OS 32-bit?

Comment: nope, 64. damn this minimum characters

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: Run `uname -a`. Does it contain `x86_64` anywhere?

Comment: in command prompt it didn't say that no. On control panel>system is says system type x64 (does that mean its not a 32 bit?

Comment: Oh god. Windows. You're doing project euler on Hard Mode.

Comment: @JoeFrambach what is hard mode?

Comment: Difficulty is higher :)

Comment: Your OS may be 64 bit, but did you install 32bit or 64bit PHP?

Comment: @seth I installed wamp stack `WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.3) 2.2E` is there a way to confirm which php i have?

Comment: @JoeFrambach that comment made me laugh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number 600851475143 is outside of the range that can be represented using integers in PHP when you have a 32bit machine, so `600851475143 / 6857` is not an integer:

```
php> var_dump(600851475143/6857);
float(87625999)
```

You can make it work if you implement the divisibility check with [`bcmod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php) from the BC arbitrary precision library:

```
php> echo bcmod('600851475143','6857');
0
```

In your code that would be:

```
for ($i=$test; $i > 1 ; $i--) { 
    if(bcmod($start, $i) == 0 && $start != $i) {
        $processArray .= "$start is divisible by $i<br />";
        $start = $i;
        $i = $test +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: On control panel>system is says system type is 64 bit

Comment: Maybe you have a 32 bit version of PHP, then. On a 64-bit machine with Linux `var_dump(600851475143/6857)` produces `int(87625999)`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are running into integer overflow. The target number 600851475143 was specifically chosen to not fit into a 32-bit integer, so this problem serves as a "gateway" to other problems that also require large integers. The solution is to use a bigger numeric datatype.

Comment: On control panel>system is says system type x64

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps PHP was compiled for 32-bit. A 64-bit OS will happily run 32-bit binaries. Go to http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php and make sure you have the 64-bit binaries installed.