# PHP make combination with exponents

Tags: php, factorization

I've been looking in to a math problem: to find the factors of a large number.
I've come to the method of "prime factorization", that all went well to code in php.
But then, say i want to know the factors of the number 196 (being: 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28, 49, 98, 196), i've found that the prime factorization of this number is: (2^2)(7^2).

To find the factors, you'll have to make all the possible combinations between the two and muttiply them:

```
(2^0)(7^0) = 1
(2^1)(7^0) = 2
(2^2)(7^0) = 4
(2^0)(7^1) = 7
(2^1)(7^1) = 14
(2^2)(7^1) = 28
(2^0)(7^2) = 49
(2^1)(7^2) = 98
(2^2)(7^2) = 196
```

This is where i'm stuck.
I need to find a function that will make a combination of these items (the exponent may not be higher then the one is the prime factorization of that number). This function will have to work on N factors (N is a number > 0 and smaller than 100).

I hope you understand my problem and have some ideas on how to solve it!

Comment: So, will this always be with regard to numbers that factor down to 2s and 7s? If so the calculations are pretty trivial since the number of iterations will always be 3N.

Comment: have you done some research? I don't think so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037688/find-the-highest-prime-number-in-a-given-range/14037923#14037923 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820112/project-euler-3-finding-prime-factors http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/gcf.php#.UaO7wUDiKzQ

Answer (score 0):

The following will print the prime factor of `$N = '196'` along with the number of exponents.

```
<?php
    function is_prime($N) {
        if($N == 2) return true;
        for($i = 3 ; $i * $i <= $N; $i++ ) {
            if($N % $i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $a = array();
    $N = '196';
    for($i = 2; $i <= $N; $i++) {
        while($N % $i == 0 && is_prime($i)) {
            if(!isset($a[$i])) {
                $a[$i] = 0;
            }
            $a[$i]++;
            $N = $N / $i;
        }
    }
    print_r($a);
?>
```